# How to create a iOS 13 Contacts App like design using UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

The native iOS Contacts App offers quite nice editing features:

- A stretchy header both in view and edit mode.
- Different row and header layout in view/edit mode
- Animations between the two modes

[image]

**How to recreate this design in my own app using UITableView?**

I know the basics of UITableView designs using its different delegate and data source methods. But there are several features where I do not know how to implement them:

**Question 1:**
How to toggle between view and edit mode using a completely different layout?

The edit mode uses a completely different layout than the view mode: More / different rows and section. Some controls disappear, others come into view.

Of course I know that a table view can toggle between view/edit mode, but can the transition used by the contacts app really be implemented using UITableView methods only or does this need transition between to completely different views?

**Question 2:**
How to create the stretchy header with the image/logo **which shrinks into the navigation bar?**

I found several other topics and tutorials about the contatcs app layout. However, most of them are several years old and since a lot has changed in iOS the offered solution are pretty outdated.

Comment: As I was saying before :) it's an interesting question but I suspect it isn't within the bounds of the tools Apple has given us. If you look at how badly behaved the ContactsUI view controllers are, esp. on iOS 13 where they are practically unusable, it's clear that something mighty peculiar is going on here.

Comment: A bit of an old question, but I stumbled upon it and figured I'd share some insight. In the current Contacts app, I would highly suspect that when it goes into `Edit` mode, it's actually pushing a new `viewController` with no animation. I don't think it's good practice to show/hide `UIView`. The stretchy header, if it's not something built in, can be achieved by scaling that `UIView` and changing its constraints. I don't believe it's out of reach of anyone.